# How can I render markers on a map in React using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, for-loop, react-google-maps

I'm experimenting with React, and I want to render a few markers on a map (I'm using Google Maps API). 
Now, everything is fine if I hardcode the markers (in the example, 5 markers, each with different coordinates, name and description, as in the locations array below). 
But what if i want to loop through the array and render them without hardcoding at all? I defined the renderMarkers function before the render(). 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
/* Main component state */
state = {
    showingInfoWindow: false,
    activeMarker: {},
    selectedPlace: {},
    mapReady: true,
    desc: '',
    animation: null,
    locations: 
  [
   {
    "locationName": "name1",
    "position": '{"lat": "lat1", "lng": "lng1"}',
    "desc": "desc1"
  },
  {
    "locationName": "name2",
    "position": '{"lat": "lat2", "lng": "lng2"}',
    "desc": "desc2"
  },
  {
    "locationName": "name3",
    "position": '{"lat": "lat3", "lng": "lng3"}',
    "desc": "desc3"
  },
  {
    "locationName": "name4",
    "position": '{"lat": "lat4", "lng": "lng4"}',
    "desc": "desc4."
  },
  {
    "locationName": "name5",
    "position": '{"lat": "lat5, "lng": "lng5"}',
    "desc": "desc5."
  }
 ]
};

/* Function to render the markers, each with their relevant info taken from the state.locations array, on the map */
renderMarkers = () => {
for (let i = 0; i < this.state.locations.length; i++) {
  return <Marker
      onClick = { this.onMarkerClick }
      title = { this.state.locations[i].locName }
      position = { JSON.parse(this.state.locations[i].position) }
      desc = { this.state.locations[i].desc }
      animation = { this.state.animation[i] }
      name = { this.state.locations[i].locName } />
   }
 }
```

Comment: Use the map() function to map over the array inside render(), this structure will make it rerender when the locations array is updated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @A.Larsson. As I'm super new to this, is it ok to declare inside of the render() function? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369296/react-functions-inside-render) says it's better not. What if I declare in the class, and then invoke it inside of the return using {}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `map` function to create an array of Markers.
2. `renderMarkers` function should be put outside of the `render` function. Otherwise `renderMarkers` will be recreated each time the component's state is changed, because `render` is invoked on each state change (performance hit).

```
renderMarkers() {
  return this.state.locations.map((location, i) => {
    return <Marker
      key={ i }
      onClick = { this.onMarkerClick }
      title = { location.locName }
      position = { JSON.parse(location.position) }
      desc = { location.desc }
      animation = { this.state.animation[i] }
      name = { location.locName } />
  })
}

render() {
  return <div>{ this.renderMarkers() }</div>
}
```

Comment: Hi @jordan, thanks for the answer. I tried following your approach, which makes a lot of sense, but I get an "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null" related to `animation = { this.state.animation[i] }`. I saved the whole component code on this [bin](https://jsbin.com/huwocah/edit?html,js,output), if you wanted to help me fix this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's because the animation is `null`. As I'm seeing you use the same animation for all the markers. So you can pass it as follow: `animation = { this.props.google.maps.Animation.DROP }` and it should work. Also the question is related to rendering an array of markers, so if my answer helps you - you can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I helped you!